# exim4 shared key permission on Debian

Tags: debian, ssl-certificate, exim

On Debian, the exim4 key file is supposed to be `/etc/exim4/exim.key` with permissions:

```
chmod 640 exim.key
chown root:Debian-exim exim.key
```

If I have already a key file in `/etc/ssl/private`, owned by group `ssl-cert`, how can I recycle it for exim?

If I change the group of `/etc/ssl/private` dir to `Debian-exim` it works, but then for instance I would need to add openldap to the `Debian-exim` group, in order to use the key for slapd. Pretty unobvious, isn't it?

Adding `Debian-exim` to the `ssl-cert` group doesn't work: it is the exim software itself to blame the configuration as unsafe.

Which is the best-practice solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use ACLs to make the key file readable by the Debian-exim group, does exim accept that?

```
setfacl -m g:Debian-exim:x /etc/ssl/private
setfacl -m g:Debian-exim:r /etc/ssl/private/key.pem
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But why doesnt beeing in the group ssl-certs grant access?

Comment: Erf. Good question. Is /etc/ssl/private executable by the ssl-cert group?

Comment: I think it has to do with exim explicitly checking for gid ownership. Merely having DAC access to it is not enough. I checked if I could read it via "sudo -u Debian-Exim" if I could read the file and that worked because I added the user to the ssl-certs group in /etc/group. But exim would not read it without your acl magic.