# Exim Unable to Read DKIM Key

Tags: linux, email, exim, opendkim

Exim is spitting out (what looks like) a privilege error:

```
# tail -n1 /var/log/exim/paniclog
2021-11-15 16:38:35.955 [682275] 1mme43-002rUN-QV unable to open file for reading: /etc/opendkim/keys/xxxxxxxxx.com/mail.private
```

despite the fact it looks as though Exim should be able to read the file

```
# namei -mo /etc/opendkim/keys/xxxxxxxxx.com/mail.private
f: /etc/opendkim/keys/xxxxxxxxx.com/mail.private
 drwxr-xr-x root     root /
 drwxr-xr-x root     root etc
 drwxr-x--- opendkim mail opendkim
 drwxr-x--- opendkim mail keys
 drwxr-x--- opendkim mail xxxxxxxxx.com
 -rw-r----- opendkim mail mail.private
$ groups exim
mail dovecot opendkim privkey exim
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: @JoelC Debian. I should mention also I've narrowed down the issue somewhat - giving the file world read permissions allows Exim to read the file. The core Exim process is running as the exim user though.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this. In my case the private key is symlinked by letsencrypt and that leads to a file path for which one of the directories is 770. Although that directory should be accessible by one of exim's groups, it seems that exim still can't enter it. Maybe it drops group privileges when it runs? I set the permissions to 775 and now exim has no problems signing a DKIM header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that works for me [here](https://serverfault.com/a/894161/931549), *mutatis mutandis*.